# Как вызвать метод объявленный из абстрактного класса в инициализации этого класса

Tags: java, ооп

Есть абстрактный класс, который имеет метод `public void SomeMethod() {}`
Как при объявлении объекта класса вызвать этот метод из переопределенного?

```
private static void AbstrClassInit() {
        Dialog abstrClass = null; // Если тут final, то (1), если нет (2)
        abstrClass = new AbstrClass() { //(1) Cannot assign a value to final variable
            @Override
            public void EscapeAction() {
                abstrClass.SomeMethod(); //(2) Variable 'abstrClass' is accesed from within inner class, needs to be declared final
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы изначально инициализируете переменную значением `null` после этого, если он финальная, её нельзя переинициализировать. Таким образом вам надо сразу инициализировать переменную экземпляром класса и сделать её финальной для доступа из внутреннего класса.

При этом вы вообще пытаетесь при определении класса вызвать метод его экземпляра... Это вы что-то не то делаете. Вам надо просто вызвать метод через `this`, коий и является ссылкой на экземпляр вашего класса.

```
private static void AbstrClassInit() {
   final Dialog abstrClass = new AbstrClass() {
        @Override
        public void EscapeAction() {
            this.SomeMethod();
    };
}
```